# Is JQuery to be used for onclick/onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jQuery and I am confused on the following:
Am I supposed to use jQuery on `onclick` or `onchange` for an element via some kind of: `$(selector).somemethod(function(){....});` ?

Comment: Try starting here: http://learn.jquery.com/events/

Comment: `$(selector).click(function(){....});` and `$(selector).change(function(){....});`

Comment: Generally `form` elements can handle the `change` events.. `inputs, textarea, checkboxes, radio` and `select`... Click events make more sense for other elements like `div, button, p..` and the list continues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure use it for either, but it's not required.

```
$(selector).on('click', function() { } );
$(selector).on('change', function() { } );
```

Comment: You mean I don't really gain something?

Comment: That all depends, of course there are advantages. Are you already using jquery for the site? Do you plan on using it for more than just event binding? If it's just for event binding I would use native js then.